# devenv /upgrade works by local powershell command but failed with gitlab job

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, gitlab, devenv, unattended-processing

I'm trying to update a solution from vs10 to vs 2017 by line command devenv `/upgrade` from a job gitlab.

The weird thing is that it works fine by launching it locally with powershell but fail with gitlab job

Example

```
devenv.exe "Src\GenATC.sln" /upgrade
```

the job at gitlab :

```
code-migration:
  stage: migration
  allow_failure: true
  tags:
    - WINDOWS
    - VS2013
  only:
    - "master"
  artifacts:
    name: Executable
    when: on_success
    expire_in: 1 week
  script:
    - '& "path to devenv\devenv.exe" "Src\GenATC.sln" /upgrade'
```

Comment: I think the `/upgrade` commands requires an interactive session to start Visual Studio and show UI. It's also not guaranteed to not block... So it's not the ideal thing to do in a pipeline. What are you trying to do that requires this, generally one-time action?

Comment: Thank you but locally we don't have to have interraction with the UI

Comment: But visual studio likely still depends on the message pump and an active windows session to work.